# Control startup window size of a program

Tags: windows-7, windows

There is a particular program that I use that whenever it starts up, its window is always too big.  I always have to resize it to make it smaller.  Is there a way I can control the size of the window when it starts up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes holding the Ctrl or Ctrl+Alt keys down when you close a window (X) will keep the size and position of the window next time it opens, it may take several tries.

Or buy this utility
http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2339650,00.asp

.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
While, 1
{
 WinWait, ahk_class [Window Class]
 WinActivate,
 WinMove,,,,,1024,768
 WinWaitClose
}
```

It's an Autohotkey script that will wait for the window to exist, resize it, and then stop until the window closes - meaning it keeps working across window-openings.

Answer (score 0):

See the free [Eusing Auto Window Manager](http://www.eusing.com/WindowManager/WindowManager.htm):

> Auto Window Manager automatically
>   manages any window you specify. For
>   instance, some web browsers open up in
>   a non-maximized window. Using Auto
>   Window Manager, you can set those
>   windows to automatically maximize
>   (minimize, normal, minimize to tray,
>   stay on top) every time they opened.
>   It works with almost any program,
>   including web browsers, Notepad, etc.
>   Auto Window Manager stays running in
>   the system tray, so it stays out of
>   your way while it works.

Comment: It doesn't resize the window on startup.

Comment: It should(must) work. Or does "startup" mean when Windows is booted?

Comment: No, it means when the program starts.  It gives options for starting minimized and maximized.  I want to start it out at a certain width and height.  It does not have that option.

Comment: The description says: "You can set the width and height of any window based on your choice".

Comment: Yes you can manually set it once it's open.  But the program doesn't give an option for doing it automatically when the program starts up.

Comment: Phenom is trying to make his life easier by having things enter the world in their proper form, rather than having to slap every child into shape as they are born. (Children are windows in this metaphor, slapping is a manual resizing in this metaphor.)

Answer (score 0):

If the program overrides the Windows-maintained settings itself, you will have to find a solution within the program (or the developers!). Otherwise, I have heard that closing the application with CTRL or ALT when clicking the [X] button in the corner can sometimes make sure an application gets it's position/size saved. I haven't got an errant application to test it on, so give it a go and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the program writers have specified a default size for their application and are using that on startup rather than saving the size and position you set during use. Which is non-standard behaviour.

Does the program "forget" it's position too?

Can you maximise the application and does it remember this state between executions?

Comment: The program forgets both its position and sized.  However, it can be maximized.

Comment: It does sound like the developers haven't programmed that behaviour into their application. Unless you can persuade the developers to make the necessary changes (it's a straightforward bit of code) you'll have to find some external way of storing the size and position.