# Windows 8.1 App (Skype) Default Window Location

Tags: windows-8.1, skype, windows-8-apps

I'm using Windows 8.1 on a non-touch Lenovo laptop. Every time I turn on my computer, the Skype Windows 8 App starts full-screen on my primary monitor. I then drag it to the secondary monitor, move it to the right-side snap view, then drag the width to the minimum.

Is there a way to tell Windows or Skype that I want Skype to always open up on the secondary monitor snap view at the minimum width? Or maybe there is an app that controls such things?

All my other Windows 8 apps I like to use full-screen, it is just Skype that I prefer as small as possible since I have it open all day.

Comment: I would report this as a bug on the Skype community website.

Comment: Check out [This Thread](http://superuser.com/questions/79757/control-startup-window-size-of-a-program) on controlling the size and location of windows on startup

Comment: Great idea Ramhound! I posted the query over at the Skype forums, I'll see if they have any insight into the issue. http://community.skype.com/t5/Modern-Windows-from-Windows/Save-App-Location/m-p/2976362#M20366